# Divisibility set of problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It may seem as a begginer question, but i was wondering if there exist a certain method to solve problems like the following :
$$1) \text{ if } n ∈ \Bbb N \\ n(n^2+5)\,⋮\,6$$
$$2)  \text{ if } n ∈ \Bbb N \\n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n\,⋮\,24$$
$$3)\text{ if } n=2k \text{ then } \frac{n}{12}+\frac{n^2}{8}+\frac{n^3}{24}∈ \Bbb Z $$

NOTE:I havent dont this types of problems in a long time and it would be useful to see a detailed solution.Thanks!a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible method is to write these numbers in terms of binomial coefficients which are always integers :

1) $$\frac{n(n^2+5)}{6}=\frac{n^3+5n}{6}=n+\frac{n^3-n}{6}=n+\frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{3!}=n+\binom{n+1}{3}$$ which is an integer so $6 \mid n(n^2+5n)$

2)  $$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n$$ so $$\frac{n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n}{24}=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4!}=\binom{n+3}{4}$$ which is an integer .

3) $$\frac{k}{6}+\frac{k^2}{2}+\frac{k^3}{3}=\frac{2k^3+3k^2+k}{6}=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$$

This can be seen either by this method :

This number is actually :

$$2\binom{k+1}{3}+\binom{k+1}{2}$$

Or you can do this in an awesome way noticing it's actually :

$$1^2+2^2+3^2+\ldots+k^2$$ (if you know this formula ) .

Answer (score 1):

When the divisor is small, you can just try all the possibilities.  For 1), there are only six remainders that are possible.  You can just try them all and see if $n(n^2+5) \equiv 0 \pmod 6$ A spreadsheet and copy down makes it easy.